# Material UI Version 0.20 to v4.3.0 upgrading

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My application was developed in older version of material UI i.e.,V0.20 and now I am planning to upgrade the material UI version to latest and add new modules to the application. I have a doubt is there any chance the developed application might break because of the new material UI upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go through the two migration guides in the documentation.

- https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/

  - This guide covers migrating from v0.x to v1
- https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

  - This guide covers migrating from v3 to v4

There wasn't a version 2 and the library jumped from [v1 to v3](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v3.0.0) in order to match the version of `@material-ui/icons`. The only breaking change in v3 was how icons should be imported.