# npm install material-ui does not install the latest version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, package.json

I have an abandoned project which is the admin tool for a current project. This project's Material-UI version was 0.19.4. When I delete the dependency from package.json and run `npm install`, it installs the version `"material-ui": "^0.20.2",` Also when i edit my package.json, Material-UI's version by hand to version "^1.0.0" the npm crashes: `No matching version found for material-ui@1.0.0.` What am I missing? Why is the latest version not installed or at least the desired version? Can anyone guide me how to approach the issue?

Side note: When I run the project with the outdated Material-UI, it is not showing as the outdated version.

Comment: no i dont need @angular/material, i'm running a react project. Why should i try this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264842/material-ui-version-0-20-to-v4-3-0-upgrading/57275229#57275229

Answer (score 4):

The newer components are now in @material-ui/core

see: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/

Answer (score 1):

`npm install @material-ui/core`

OR

`yarn add @material-ui/core`

Comment: does not matter. Both does the same job. you can do it either with npm or yarn

Answer (score 1):

There are some factors that may be causing the installation to fail. One that I know is maybe the version of npm is not the latest.

Try:

> $ npm -g install npm

After that, try installing material-ui again.
That would work.

Comment: Irrespective of the current create-react-app version (which is 16.0.1 Latest), first making global npm version to 16.4.8 with npm -g install npm. Then install Material UI with npm install @material-ui/core. This resolves all dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I manage it by the following command

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @material-ui/core
```

!use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

**Run this:**

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

`//then install your npm`